# How to generate product id that contains letter and numbers in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

How can I create a line of code in c# that I will use to give every new product that I add to my product table?I am using MySQL database. 
 This is what I have tried so far although it's not what I really need.

```
//auto product number
static string IncrementID(string startValue, int numNonDigits)
{
    string nonDigits = startValue.Substring(0, numNonDigits);
    int len = startValue.Length - numNonDigits;
    int number = int.Parse(startValue.Substring(numNonDigits));
    number++;
    if (number >= Math.Pow(10, len)) number = 1; // start again at 1
    return String.Format("{0}{1:D" + len.ToString() + "}", nonDigits, number);
}
private void Genarate_productcode()
{
    product_code.Text = IncrementID("QIEpl/PO/0000009", 9); // produces QIEpl/PO/0000010 // C00011 PCI0001
}
```

Comment: What are the requirements for the ID? There's a few different ways of creating unique `strings`.

Comment: the first two should be a letter followed by a number and back slash and then the word POS. for example PC01/POS